# How to setup a inheritance using building object as an example

Tags: java, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

In JAVA, I plan on making a building class with the following attributes: static stockColors (static ArrayList of strings of color names), double area, int numDoors, int numWindows, String color. In the end this class with creating an instance with all the attributes (area, color, numDoors, numWindows). Also, methods should include getters and setters for all attributes. (This is supposed to be the parent class).

If the color specified for the object is not in the list, in your constructor make sure to print and tell the user it is an invalid color and choose one of the stock colors at random.

I am not sure how to start or even work on this please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Building class should look something similar to below. stockColors is an arraylist and it has got a contains method that takes an object and check if the color is present or not. You can basically use it to check and filter out a color and return a boolean if the color is not present.

```
public class Building {
List < String > stockColors;
double area;
int numDoors;
int numWindows;
String color;

public Building(List < String > stockColors, double area, int numDoors, int numWindows, String color) {

    this.stockColors = stockColors;
    this.area = area;
    this.numDoors = numDoors;
    this.numWindows = numWindows;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Building [stockColors=" + stockColors + ", area=" + area + ", numDoors=" + numDoors + ", numWindows=" +
        numWindows + ", color=" + color + "]";
}

public List < String > getStockColors() {
    return stockColors;
}

public void setStockColors(List < String > stockColors) {
    this.stockColors = stockColors;
}

public double getArea() {
    return area;
}

public void setArea(double area) {
    this.area = area;
}

public int getNumDoors() {
    return numDoors;
}

public void setNumDoors(int numDoors) {
    this.numDoors = numDoors;
}

public int getNumWindows() {
    return numWindows;
}

public void setNumWindows(int numWindows) {
    this.numWindows = numWindows;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
```

}